# getVisualBounds() return a dimension with all 0

Tags: java

The following code failed to read bounding rectangle of given korean text & font (NotoSansCJKKr-Regular.otf font), despite the fact that it works well on other Google fonts. What is the problem here anyway?

```
String text = "안녕하세요";
BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(1, 1 , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)buf.getGraphics();
setRenderingHints(g2);
FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
GlyphVector glyph = g2.getFont().createGlyphVector(frc, text);
Rectangle rect = glyph.getVisualBounds().getBounds();
```

Result rect:

`java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]`

Comment: Without doing anything (using the default Font), it outputs `java.awt.Rectangle[x=1,y=-10,width=58,height=11]`, so I suspect that it's an issue with the Font

Comment: @MadProgrammer Look like you are right. The font is open type & if I replace it with truetype font, then it works.